# How to use Jquery slide toggle here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".toggle").click(function () {
    //$(".readmore").slideToggle();
    $(".readmore").toggle();
    $(this).text(function(){return $('.readmore:visible').length?'Read less':'Read more'});
  }).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

I would like a slidetoggle effect on clicking on Readmore, however as soon as i replace toggle with slidetoggle, it stops working. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

> [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/): with no parameters simply toggles the visibility of elements

Instead, [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) requires a animation time to complete. That means you need to use the **complete** callback: a function to call once the animation is complete.

So, when you test for the visibility after slideToggle it doesn't work because this value changes only after a timeout while with toggle it changes soon. Due to this delay you need to wait for animation to be **complete** to execute your code.

In the following the snippet:

```js
$(".toggle").on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).nextAll(".readmore:first").slideToggle(400, function() {
        $(e.target).text($('.readmore:visible').length?'Read less':'Read more');
    });
});

$(".readmore").toggle();
$('.toggle').text($('.readmore:visible').length?'Read less':'Read more');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="toggle">Read more</button><br/>
<div class="readmore">
blah blah blah
</div>
<button class="toggle">Read more</button><br/>
<div class="readmore">
blah blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, any ideas why this code is expanding all the div's on the page when hitting read more on within one div, surely as there are no Div id's being used here it should only affect the read more div that is being executed? Do i need to add a for each loop around it or something, to stop all instances on the page being affected?

Comment: @justanotherrrr Snippet updated. It's expanding all divs because the code selects elements by class. It's required to select the first next sibling with thaat class..

Comment: Thanks for the help, so i updated to test your jquery with my html, and it broke my page :) any ideas why?

Comment: Please,  add html or create a fiddle. It's impossible to guess with this few info.

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".readmore").hide();
  $(".toggle").click(function (event) {
    $(this).nextAll(".readmore:first").slideToggle(function(){    
      $(event.target).text(function(){
        return $('.readmore:visible').length?'Read less':'Read more'});
    });
  });
});
```

The HTML part

```
<button class="toggle">
Read more
</button>
<div class="readmore">
blah blah blah
</div>
```

the slidetoggle have default animation time of 300ms which you can increase , just change the slidetoggle callback(3 lines) to the following:

```
$(this).nextAll(".readmore:first").slideToggle(500,function(){    
      $(event.target).text(function(){
        return $('.readmore:visible').length?'Read less':'Read more'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, any ideas why this code is expanding all the div's on the page when hitting read more on within one div, surely as there are no Div id's being used here it should only affect the read more div that is being executed?

Comment: you are using class .readmore not id. If id attribute is given the it should be called $("#readmore").slidetoggle().